# Bouncy Castle Signature Algorithm Issue porting to 1.60 from 1.48

Tags: bouncycastle, signature

I am trying to upgrade from 1.48 version to 1.60 and running into an issue with Signature Algorithms.

Below is the old code and new code.  The value for signing algorithm previously was the OID value.  After updating the code, this fails.  The signingAlgorithm now must be a string representation of the name instead of the OID.

First question is there a way to lookup the name based upon the OID within BC?

Second question(if there isn't a way to do lookup), then does anyone know the what the mappings should be.  I have attempted to map SHA1(see below) but can't find equivalent for MD5.

SHA1(oid=1.3.14.3.2.26 mapped name = SHA1WITHRSAANDMGF1)?
MD5(oid=1.2.840.1.13549.2.5 mapped name = ?)

Previous Code

```
signer.addSigner(privateKey, (X509Certificate) privateCertChain[0],
        signingAlgorithm, new AttributeTable(attributes), null);
```

New Code

```
SignerInfoGenerator signerInfoGenerator = new JcaSimpleSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder().setProvider(
        "BC").setSignedAttributeGenerator(new AttributeTable(attributes)).build(
        signingAlgorithm, privateKey, privateCertChain[0]);
```

Comment: You may want to ask this on the Bouncy Castle Dev mailing list instead. But please note that using MD5 as hash algorithm for RSA / PSS is like putting diesel in a Ferrari.

Comment: No types for anything? What are the types for `signer`, `privateKey`, `privateCertChain`, `signingAlgorithm`?

Comment: How are the values relevant for this question?  As stated, the signingAlgorithm in the previous code example would be "1.3.14.3.2.26" and now that value no longer works.  Rather it must be a String value instead of OID like 'SHA1WITHRSAANDMGF1".   Looks like I will post this on the BC Mailing List instead